How operations are awaited when invoking asynchronous functions
I'm practicing for an interview assessment which uses Adaface (https://www.adaface.com/assessment-test/javascript-online-test).
The question is what is the output of this code:


function after5s(x) {
  return new Promise(res => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      res(x);
    }, 5000);
  });
}

async function mult(input) {
  const f = await after5s(3);
  const g = await after5s(4);
  return input * f * g;
}

mult(2).then(value => {
  console.log(value);
});

async function second_mult(input) {
  const f = after5s(3);
  const g = after5s(4);
  return input * await f * await g;
}

second_mult(2).then(value => {
  console.log(value);
});



I thought the answer to this question would be that it waits 10 secs and 24 is outputted, then 5 secs for another 24 to be outputted but they're saying the correct answer is: 24 after 5 seconds and after another 5 seconds, another 24.
I don't understand the answer to this javascript question, can someone explain?

How did you arrive at your answer?

The first 24 that's logged is from the second_mult (5s), then the second 24 that's logged is from mult (10s total, but appears 5s after the second_mult log). The timers in second_mult begin while the timer in mult is already created and running.

Change (2) to different numbers, so you can tell what is being output when. Having the same output makes this super confusing. If you use mult(3) and second_mult(4), you get 48 (second_mult) after 5 seconds, and 36 (mult) after another 5 seconds, 10 seconds after the actual call to mult(3).

The correct answer is that the second_mult implementation is a horrible practice that should not be used.


I thought the answer to this question would be that it waits 10 secs and 24 is outputted, then 5 secs for another 24

The subtle part they wanted you to notice is that the top-level operations are not being awaited.  So you're correct that this would take 10 seconds:
mult(2).then(value => {
  console.log(value);
});

And you're correct that this would take 5 seconds:
second_mult(2).then(value => {
  console.log(value);
});

However, they're both invoked immediately and both begin waiting.  So after 5 seconds the latter one prints its output, then after another 5 seconds (so 10 total) the former one prints its output.

A little more detail on the latter case...
There are indeed two await operations here:
async function second_mult(input) {
  const f = after5s(3);
  const g = after5s(4);
  return input * await f * await g;
}

But what makes them different (and is perhaps another subtle thing they wanted you to notice in the interview) is that they're being awaited after the operation was already invoked.  So after both setTimeout calls have simultaneously (or close enough to it) begun ticking.
So while technically await g doesn't happen until after await f completes, by the time we get to await g that setTimeout has already completed.  So what we're awaiting is now ready and resolves.
Whereas in the former example the second setTimeout operation isn't even invoked until after the first one is fully awaited and resolves.

Can you confirm: The difference in mult() is that g = await .. only starts after f = await .. completes (thus 10s), but in second_mult() it's only 5 seconds, not 10 because g=after5s starts at the same time as f=after5s so the 2x awaits in the return run at the same time (thus 5s)

@fdomn-m: Good call, additional details added.

…also, this really should use await Promise.all([f, g]) instead
